Re-Activate Post-Alarm-Clock News Reader on Android
Android's alarm app offers a feature to read the current/latest news from selected sources. It consists of text-to-voice for today's weather and appointments and a collection of different news podcast by the actual publisher.
This feature starts as soons as you stop the alarm. But sometimes it's not even starting. If you pause it for too long, when having a phone call in parallel, it's being closed automatically. And yeah, sometimes, not often, it crashes.
So I am in the "desperate" need of finding a way to manually start this "reading feature".
There are several problems preventing that:

this is not part of the official news app (which is not even required on the phone)
it's not a seperate app on the phone
a couple of weeks ago you could start it manually using the assistantg (Hey Google, read the current news)
not even Gemini knows a valid answer (neither does ChatGPT or Claude, I asked them all)

Please note: I don't want to know how to enable it in the alarm app, I want to start the "reading app" (it's more a process or part of the alarm app) manually. I also don't want to install a different app or use Spotify/Deezer. Also I don't want to workaround it by setting an alarm for 1 Minute in the future. There must be a valid, user friendly solution that my "AI powered Smartphone" offers.

AFAIK, this is a function of Google Assistant. You could try checking on Google app - Settings - Google Assistant - Routines. Then see if there's a routine called "Good morning".

Thanks @AndrewT. - there's no such routine, I could probably add one, but honestly: that's the way of workaround I'd like to avoid, if there's no better/easier solution

If that's the case, could you mention the device model, Android version, and the Clock/Alarm app, just in case it's relevant? I still think this is Google Assistant's "Good morning" routine with the starter alarm dismissed, and it can also be activated by saying "Good morning" to Google Assistant (on my stock Pixel 3a), but I don't know how/if other manufacturers implement it differently.

"Good Morning" is not working, but I found the solution, see answer... thanks anyway!

When in the settings for my Google account (locally, on my phone), I have to select "Assistant" and then "Digital Assistant" - I can switch back to "Google Assistant" from "Gemini". No again, I can activate the news reading feature again.
I remember how the phone at some point asked me about that switch and I didn't realized the impact of that (I don't even understand, why they ever offer this option, Gemini is not really an assistant, as my case proves).
